# read txt file and store each category(make,color,year) into a different ArrayList

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

trying to read txt file and store each category(make,color,year) into different ArrayLists and then display all the data in the array list.

*what im getting*

```
*****Welcome *****
setup
```

*so by going System.out.println(make.get(i)) etc. I get*

```
toyota 
subaru
honda

blue
black 
white

2010
2001
2003
```

*the text file looks like this*

```
3 
#car
#make
Toyota
#Color 
Blue
#year
2010
##
#car
#make
subaru
#color
black
#year
2003
##
#car
#make
honda
#Color
white
#year
2001
##
```

> the 3 at the tells how much cars are in the garage
> the "##" represents the end of the car details

**code**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class testApp {

        static ArrayList<String> year= new ArrayList<>();
        static ArrayList<String> make = new ArrayList<>();
        static ArrayList<String> colors = new ArrayList<>();
    private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        
        System.out.println("*****Welcome*****");

        try {
            garage();
           

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    
    public static void garage() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
      
        System.out.println("setup");
        String filename = "garage.txt";
        String showError = "Error input file " + filename + " is not formmated properly.";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)));

      
        String line = reader.readLine();

        if (line == null) {
            reader.close();
            throw new IOException(showError);
        }

        int numCar= Integer.parseInt(line);

        System.out.println("num ques " + numCar);

        int carCount = 0;

        //loop to look for each car 
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && carCount < numCar) {

          //  System.out.println("reading");

            if (line.equals("#car")) {
               
                // System.out.println("q");
                while ((line = reader.readLine().trim()) != null) {
                   
                    if (!line.equals("##")) {
                       
                        //reads car
                        if (line.equals("#make")) {
                            make.add(reader.readLine());
                         
                            System.out.println("q 1 "+make.get(0));
                        }

                        if (line.equals("#color")) {
                            System.out.println("make orig= " + reader.readLine());
                            colors.add(reader.readLine());
                           
                        }
                        if (line.equals("#year")) {
                            year.add(reader.readLine());
                            System.out.println("ans orig= " + reader.readLine());
                            //color = readAnswer(reader.readLine(),car);
                        }

                    } else {
                        break;
                    }

                }
            
                carCount++;
            }
        }
        
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       System.out.println(make.get(i));
       System.out.println(year.get(i));
       System.out.println(colors.get(i));
       }
         
        

    }

  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - one change in line 13 (garage.txt) making it color -> Color.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class TestApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String filename = "garage.txt";
        File file = new File(filename);
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line = null;
        StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("");
        int count = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (count == 0) {
                count = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
            } else {
                joiner.add(line.trim());
            }
        }
        String[] carDetails = joiner.toString().split("###");

        ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> colors = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> years = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String details : carDetails) {
            String car = details.split("#make")[1].split("#Color")[0];
            cars.add(car);
            String color = details.split("#make")[1].split("#Color")[1].split("#year")[0];
            colors.add(color);
            String year = details.split("#make")[1].split("#Color")[1].split("#year")[1];
            year = year.replace("#", "");
            years.add(year);
        }
        for (String car : cars) {
            System.out.println(car);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (String color : colors) {
            System.out.println(color);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (String year : years) {
            System.out.println(year);
        }
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to use an array list? i have to use an arraylist

Comment: Updated with array list.